# Is it possible to redirect to google password page with out showing email page to user in C# web application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm working on C# web application project, need to implement a googe sign in.
Implementation concept is we have a login page, when user enter email id, we will validate it in our db to check its exist if yes, then it should redirect to googles password page.

Else not, user should login to our application with email id registered in our DB not with all gmail ids.

So now my page is directing to googles page there we can enter different email id, so is it possible to redirect directly to googles password page or any other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mostly depends on the authentication provider you are using, but the default flow would be similar to the following:

```
//use your logic to make the check
if ( isEmailFromGoogle( email ) )
{
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
        Items =
        {
            { "scheme", provider },
            { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
            { "login_hint", email }
        }
    };
    return Challenge( props, "Google" );
}
```

The `"login_hint"` property is a special Google login parameter, which you can use to provide tha user's e-mail address to prefill.

The `Challenge` is a result that will trigger the external authentication provider, in this case Google. It is a kind of `HttpUnauthorizedResult` and it is built in ASP.NET Core, but also part of the default ASP.NET MVC template when you select user authentication when creating the project.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I'm pre-filling email id but user should hit sign in again. Instead of it that hit can be made while calling redirect URL?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that his on Google's authentication and you cannot influence that process...

Comment: If that answers the question, please accept the answer so to indicate it is closed :-) .